# drawing a path and then an image in html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to draw a circle and then have an image follow the circle around. Later I want to rotate and move the image around with respect to the circle drawn. The problem I'm facing is that when I try to rotate the image it won't rotate. It also doesn't show me an error in the console. I have functions allowing me to move the circle around and the image moves with it, I just can't seem to rotate the image.

Here is the code:

```
draw: function(){
//draw self on canvas;
//intended only to be called from update, should never
//need to be deliberately called
ctx = this.context;

ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle="#000000";
ctx.beginPath();

//void arc(double x, double y,
//         double radius, double startAngle, double endAngle,
//          optional boolean anticlockwise = false);
ctx.arc(this.x,this.y,this.size,0,Math.PI*2,true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
//ctx.translate(this.x, this.y);
ctx.rotate(this.imgAngle);
//draw the hammer

ctx.drawImage(this.hammer,this.hammerX,this.hammerY,100,100)
ctx.rotate(Math.PI/2);

ctx.restore();

},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/qhfxQ/)**

Try changing your code to the following. You need to perform the rotation before drawing. You can translate the canvas to the entities position and then draw the image at `x:0,y:0` to get the effect you desire. Note I did `0-50,0-50` because that puts the point of origin in the center since the width and height are 100. Meaning your image will rotate around its center rather than around its corner.

```
//draw the hammer
ctx.translate(this.hammerX, this.hammerY);
ctx.rotate(this.imgAngle);
ctx.drawImage(this.hammer,0-50,0-50,100,100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The rotation will only affect drawings made AFTER the rotation is done.

You could try moving the rotate calls to just before the object that needs to be rotated?